# Strings.InStr and Strings.InStrRev producing different results

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Using `Visual Studio 2019` and `Visual Basic`. The following test program produces a result I cannot explain. The forward search using `InStr` correctly finds "joe" with [a case-insensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-compare-statement) `CompareMethod.Text`. But the reverse search `InStrRev` does NOT find "joe"...why?

```
Dim msg As String = "According to Joe, this is a beautiful day. Joe rides a bicycle!"
Dim joe As String = "Joe"
Dim joeLower As String = "joe"

Console.WriteLine(InStr(msg, joe))                             ' 14 => found, expected
Console.WriteLine(InStr(msg, joeLower))                        ' 0 => not found, expected
Console.WriteLine(InStr(msg, joeLower, CompareMethod.Text))    ' 14 => found, expected

Console.WriteLine(InStrRev(msg, joe))                          ' 44 => found, expected
Console.WriteLine(InStrRev(msg, joeLower))                     ' 0 => not found, expected
Console.WriteLine(InStrRev(msg, joeLower, CompareMethod.Text)) ' 0 => not found, why?
```

Comment: Maybe don't use these legacy replica functions intended to provide comfort for VB6 programmers.. I doubt you'd have run into any problems if you'd used the modern .NET version -  `msg.LastIndexOf(joe,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` ..

Comment: @CaiusJard except that InstrRev is 3/4 times faster than LastIndexOf [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WlxkFJ) Still agree with you though

Comment: @CaiusJard: Thanks! Not a fan of VB, picking up a legacy product originally written in VB6 and recently "translated" to VB.NET. Will look to use the modern .NET equivalents.

Comment: @Steve yes, I suppose InStrRev might be a bit faster if you start it at index `(int)CompareMethod.Text` (but it did amuse me that you went and put the OP's faulty code into the Fiddle after telling them why it wasn't working) - try this one https://dotnetfiddle.net/TD1FKj

Comment: Ahh, copy paste hits again. Then there is no real difference.

Comment: @Steve, all those old VB6 methods are .NET reimplementations and, not surprisingly, `InStrRev` actually uses `String.LastIndexOf` internally anyway. There's a whole bunch of other stuff before that though, to ensure that it behaves exactly as it did in VB6. As a result, while the difference would be negligible, `InStrRev` would actually be marginally slower. This is an example of why these old methods should not be used in the first place. They generally end up using the .NET alternative anyway, so you'd be better off using it yourself.

Comment: If I use overload that does NOT use `CompareMethod` and `StringComparison`, then `InStr` is ~3-5 times faster than `IndexOf`...see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qy9G8d. Is that expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing as the third parameter the **CompareMethod.Text** value instead of the value for the index where the search should start. Default should be -1 (or from the end of the string)

```
Console.WriteLine(InStrRev(msg, joeLower, -1, CompareMethod.Text)) ' => 44
```

The last two parameters in InStrRev are both optional, and because [CompareMethod.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.comparemethod?view=net-5.0) is equal to the integer 1, the search starts at the index 1 going to zero checking just one character and, of course, no match is found.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that if start index is in the middle of a word, InStrRev won't find the word

Comment: Ah, yes! I was fooled by the overloads for `InStr` and missed that there wasn't an overload *sans* `start` for `InStrRev`. Confusing API choice to overload one but not the other...